# Can't get user email

Tags: django-allauth

here is my settings.php concerning facebook:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
    { 'facebook':
          { 'METHOD': 'js_sdk',
            'SCOPE' : [ 'email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends' ],
            'FIELDS': [
                'id',
                'email',
                'name',
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'locale',
                'timezone',
                'gender' ],
            'VERIFIED_EMAIL': True,
            } }
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
```

Despite this, django allauth won't grab user's email and all social accounts have empty email. Was there a change at facebook that won't allow user's email access or something missing from my setting ?